# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined for JQuery DataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I have bound my datatable to my gridview in ASP.Net. I Have tried to use jQuery dataTable to show search and sorting options in my gridview, but the datatable throws me an error.

The Error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" this is the error.

I have used the below code:

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    $('#grdProducts').DataTable(
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.dataTable').dataTable();
        })
    );
}
```

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="grdProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover dataTable">
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProductID" runat="server"                        Text='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" HeaderText="Group Name" />--%>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BrandID" HeaderText="Brand" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ShortCode" HeaderText="Code " />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" class="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnUpdate_OnClick" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 9):

By default ASP GridView keeps everything under  tag and will not render grid header under , which will result in 'mData' error.

In order to do so, use below line after binding data to GridView:

```
GridViewName.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Comment: All the things I have tried but this line is working for me on my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below instead:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#grdProducts').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: I have used it before. Using it, i don't get any error but the things i want search option, sorting option in the gridview does to come.
             $('#grdProducts').DataTable(
                   $(document).ready(function () {
                       $('.dataTable').dataTable(
                        {
                          "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': true, 'aTargets': [4, 5, 6, 7] }]
                        } ); }));

I have added this code which i found in the web. after using it i am getting :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined 
this error.

Comment: @AtiburRahman I encountered `Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined` because my interpolated table had some **columnspan** `<td>`s!!! My DataTables is DOM initiated (not JavaScript or AJAX data, but DOM initiated). Maybe that's what you are running into, just telling to spare some hours possibly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function pageLoad() 
{
  var table = $('#grdProducts').DataTable
  ({
       //Here you can define other things using Var table
  });    
}
```

You can add it on page load or Row databound

```
grdProducts.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
//adds <thead> and <tbody> elements
grdProducts.HeaderRow.TableSection =
TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```